# Keras load_model takes forever after layer name update

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I have a custom classification model. I need to change the name of last convolution layer for some reason. Model loads in 7 to 9 seconds before the update but after the name change it takes forever. I couldn't find any reason for that.
I saved the model using `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint()` in the first place.

This is how I update:

```py
best_acc_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("path/to/model")
best_acc_model.get_layer("conv_name")._name = "new_conv_name"
best_acc_model.save("save/path")
```

And this is how I load the updated model:

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("save/path", compile=False)
```

There is nothing fancy but some how it takes forever to load and does not raise any exception.
Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is;

```
best_acc_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("path/to/model")
best_acc_model.get_layer("conv_name")._name = "new_conv_name"
best_acc_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=best_acc_model.input, outputs=best_acc_model.output)
best_acc_model.save("save/path")
```

Source: [link to solution](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14356#issuecomment-974558020)